# obtener el índice minimo de un List en un programa

Tags: python

Tengo un problema en Python. Quiero obtener el índice minimo de un List:

```
for j in range(nbr_usines):
    L.append(Dij[j][i])
indice_min=L.index(min(L))
```

En el terminal esta bueno con `L.index(min(L))`, pero cuando compilo el programa `programa(Bij,Dij,Vi,Pi)` me dice :

```
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error se produce porque estas aplicando `min()` sobre una **lista vacía**. Puedes reproducirlo con:

```
L=[]
indice_min=L.index(min(L))
```

Por alguna razón `L` es una lista vacía, posiblemente, dado lo que muestras, se deba a que `nbr_usines` valga 0). Si esto no debe pasar revisa tu código porque estás generando mal la lista. En cambio, si esta posibilidad existe de forma natural en tu programa, entonces debes controlar la excepción.
Una solución sería usar un condicional que compruebe si la lista está o no vacía:

```
if L:
    indice_min = L.index(min(L))
else:
    indice_min = None
```

O de forma más compacta:

```
indice_min = L.index(min(L)) if L else None
```

O usar `try-except`:

```
for j in range(nbr_usines):
    L.append(Dij[j][i])

try:
    indice_min = L.index(min(L))
except ValueError:
    indice_min = None
```

Si necesitas también el elemento en si además de su índice tienes otras posibilidades:

- Usar un generador y `enumerate`:

  ```
  if L:
      valor, indice = min((v,i) for i,v in enumerate(L))
  else:
      valor, indice = None, None
  ```

  Lo mismo en una línea:

  ```
  valor, indice = min((v,i) for i,v in enumerate(L)) if L else (None, None)
  ```
- Usar `operator.itemgetter` junto a `enumerate`:

  ```
  import operator

  if L:
      indice, valor = min(enumerate(L), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
  else:
      indice, valor = None, None
  ```

  o alternativamente:

  ```
  import operator

  indice, valor = min(enumerate(L), key=operator.itemgetter(1)) if L else (None, None)
  ```

En todos los casos si la lista está vacía se retorna `None`, puedes modificar esto como quieras dependiendo del uso que le des en tu programa completo.